# "Does it change anything" or "Is it changes anything"?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

Which sentence is correct?

> Does it change anything?

or

> Is it changes anything?

How would native speaker say something like this?

Comment: I think the first one seems correct but still not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the first example is grammatical and the second is not.

English speakers use **auxilliary** (or *helping*) verbs in front of nouns and pronouns to ask questions, with the main verb following. For example, they say:

> Does it change (something)
>
> Will it change (something)
>
> Might it change (something)

In each case **it** itself might change or you could add **something** (an object, using the verb transitively.)

And in the past:

> Has it changed (something)
>
> Had it changed (something)
>
> Did it change (something)

Adding an object makes the difference between saying:

> He has changed since I saw him last (intransitive)

and

> He has changed his clothes since I saw him last. (transitive)

However, you cannot add an object after **is** and **was**.

So you can legitimately ask:

> Is it changed

meaning **has it undergone a change itself**

but you **cannot say**:

> Is/was it changed something

You have to ask:

> Has it changed something

or

> Did it change something